# JavaScript RegExp Replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Not sure where I am doing wrong.  I have a string such as Test (123x) and I am trying to find the (123x) and replace it with nothing:

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var original = "Test (1x)";
    var newString = original.replace(new RegExp("\(\d{1,6}[x]{1}\)",original),"");
    console.log(newString);
</script>
```

I have tested the regex pattern and it matches correctly, however, when I log to the console, it's not replacing (1x) with ""

Comment: You might want to use the regular expression syntax to make your code a bit shorter: `original.replace(/\(\d{1,6}[x]{1}\)/, "")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the *RegExp* literals when possible:

```
var original = "Test (1x)";
var newString = original.replace(/\(\d{1,6}[x]{1}\)/,"");
```

Your attempt fails as `"\(\d{1,6}[x]{1}\)"` is interpreted as `"(d{1,6}[x]{1})"` (`\‍` are simply stripped for unknown escape sequences). You would need to escape the `\` as well:

```
new RegExp("\\(\\d{1,6}[x]{1}\\)",original)
```

Besides that, the second parameter for the *RegExp* constructor is for the flags (`g`=global replace, `i`=case insensitive, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Passing `original` to the `RegExp` is wrong. You also have to escape every slash in the string (so that it produces a slash for the regex) as `\` is the escape character in JS strings:

```
original.replace(new RegExp("\\(\\d{1,6}[x]{1}\\)"),"");
```

Note that `[x]{1}` is the same as writing `x` directly.

You could also use a *regex literal*:

```
/\(\d{1,6}x\)/
```

Comment: Makes sense, since replace is called on original, but this still logs Test (1x)