# Javascript - Replace a Regex with another Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string (0511 51 51 86 86 for example) in my web page (may have multiple occurrences), and I want to replace them with another string (0511 51 51 86 86* in this case), using the Regular Expression.

I have tried with replace() function, to find all the occurrences and replace. This works fine with strings as parameter in replace(). But doesn't if I use Regex.

I have tried this:

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/0\d{3} \d{2} \d{2} \d{2} \d{2}/g, /0\d{3} \d{2} \d{2} \d{2} \d{2}\*/g));
```

What I want is, replace all this: 0511 51 51 86 86 with that: 0511 51 51 86 86* using the Regular Expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230010/javascript-regexp-replace)

Answer (score 0):

In your replacement string, you can use `$&` to include all of the replaced text. So:

```
replacement = original.replace(/\d{4}(?: \d{2}){4}/g, "$&*");
```

Example:

```js
const original = "blah blah blah 0511 51 51 86 86 blah blah blah";
const replacement = original.replace(/\d{4}(?: \d{2}){4}/g, "$&*");
console.log(replacement);
```

You've asked:

> Is this legal: `$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/\d{4}(?: \d{2}){4}/g, "$&*"));` I am using `$("body").html()` since I don't have a specific string. The whole web page content is there.

Yes, but it's a very bad idea. It tears down the page entirely (removing any event handlers or element data that may have been attached) and replaces it with a new page that's the result of parsing the HTML all over again.

Instead, use a simple recursive function to update the text nodes of the page:

```
const rex = /\d{4}(?: \d{2}){4}/g;

function doReplacement(element) {
    for (let child = element.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3) {        // A text node
            child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(rex, "$&*");
        } else if (child.nodeType === 1) { // An element
            doReplacement(child);
        }
    }
}

doReplacement(document.body);
```

Live Example:

```js
const rex = /\d{4}(?: \d{2}){4}/g;

function doReplacement(element) {
    for (let child = element.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3) {        // A text node
            child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(rex, "$&*");
        } else if (child.nodeType === 1) { // An element
            doReplacement(child);
        }
    }
}

doReplacement(document.body);
```

```html
blah blah blah 0511 51 51 86 86 blah blah blah
<p>
  blah blah blah 0511 50 52 68 68 blah blah blah
  <span>
    blah blah blah 0511 49 27 67 24 blah blah blah
  </span>
</p>
<div>
  blah blah blah 0511 51 51 86 86 blah blah blah
  <p>
    blah blah blah 0511 50 52 68 68 blah blah blah
    <span>
      blah blah blah 0511 49 27 67 24 blah blah blah
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for nice solution. Is this legal: $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/\d{4}(?: \d{2}){4}/g, "$&*"));

I am using $("body").html() since I don't have a specific string. The whole web page content is there.

Comment: @লুটুপুটু - I've answered that comment using an edit to the answer. Happy coding!